# VB.Net access the same member on different objects

Tags: vb.net

Often I have to write structures where logic is performed on each member variable for a class. For example, in this code I am finding anything that has changed between the object and another object, then returning the changes:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public B1 As Boolean?
    Public B2 As Boolean?
    ...
    Public B1000 As Boolean?

    Function GetChanges(F as Foo) As Foo
        Dim Changes As New Foo()

        If Not B1.Equals(F.B1) Then
            B1 = F.B1
            Changes.B1 = F.B1
        End If

        If Not B2.Equals(F.B2) Then
            B2 = F.B2
            Changes.B2 = F.B2
        End If

       ...

        If Not B1000.Equals(F.B1000) Then
            B1000 = F.B100
            Changes.B1000 = F.B1000
        End If

        Return Changes
    End Function
End Class
```

As you can see, the same "If Not X.Equals(F.X) ..." has to be copy pasted many many times.

Here is a second example where I am taking the changes calculated before, and using them to update the value of the Foo object.

```
    Sub Update(Changes as Foo)
        If Changes.B1.HasValue Then
            B1 = Changes.B1
        End If

        If Changes.B2.HasValue Then
            B2 = Changes.B2
        End If

        ...

        If Changes.B1000.HasValue Then
            B1000 = Changes.B1000
        End If
    End Sub
```

This kind of structure isn't something I'm happy with. It's fragile, it's ugly, it's repetitive. Is there something I can do about it?

One option is to pass the 3 members by ref, but the problem is you still have these 3 calls to the same variable, which is still repeditive:

```
Public Shared Sub CheckChange(Of T)(ByRef OldV As T, NewV As T, ByRef Change As T)
    If Not OldV.Equals(NewV) Then
        OldV = NewV
        Change = NewV
    End If
End Sub


Function GetChanges(F as Foo) As Foo
    Dim Changes As New Foo()

    CheckChange(B1, F.B1, Changes.B1)
    CheckChange(B2, F.B2, Changes.B2)
    ...
    CheckChange(B1000, F.B1000, Changes.B1000)

    return Changes
End Function
```

It would be great if I could do something like:

```
Sub CheckChanges(F as Foo, ByRef Changes as Foo, Member as ???)
    If Not Member.Equals(F.Member) Then
        Member = F.Member
        Changes.Member = F.Member
    End If
End Sub

Function GetChanges(F as Foo) As Foo
    Dim Changes As New Foo()

    CheckChange(F, Changes, B1)
    CheckChange(F, Changes, B2)
    ...
    CheckChange(F, Changes, B1000)

    return Changes
End Function
```

I'm not even sure what that kind of feature would be called. Relative member referencing? Anyway, is there any kind of feature (this, or otherwise) that would make the code more robust when having to run the same logic on multiple members?

Comment: You're not passing pointers; you're passing references. Apart from that, the only reason to pass a reference type (i.e. class) by reference is if you want to assign a new object to that parameter inside the method and have that change reflected outside the method. There are very few cases of your doing that in the code you have shown and there's no way you'd need all those parameters declared `ByRef` for code you haven't shown. If you are passing an object as an argument and all you want to do is set properties or fields of that object then you pass by value, not by reference.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Technically true but I think it's not that rare to refer to references as pointers. I'm not sure it's totally necessary to be pedantic, but you are correct. I don't think it's possible to update the value of a variable on a parent object without passing it byref. For example if you call "sub foo(i as integer) i = 0" and then "bar.i = 1" "foo(bar.i)" then afterwards bar.i will be unchanged. So that's why I need to pass byref when manipulating members. Otherwise the changes will be unrelated to the parent, and so the function won't do anything.

Comment: You have a thousand boolean props on a class and each of them is backed by its own variable. Your life would be much easier if they were backed by one array 1000 big, and each prop retrieved a different array index, then all you'd need to do your compares etc is one loop

Comment: jmc is making the point that creating a method foo() that fiddles with another object's i wrong. If I is to be altered by a method it should be by a method foo declared on the bar object. Stuff like Int.TryParse is an outlier to this rule; it has to be able to modify your variable x that you pass in because it needs to return the bool of whether it parsed or not. It isn't a pattern that you should adopt (don't do `Dim myX = 0; If foreignObject.FiddledWith(myX) Then Console.Write("myX has a new value courtesy of foreignObject:" & myX)`)

Comment: @CaiusJard This is example code. Dumping everything in the class into an array object is possible, but not an ideal solution for production code IMO.

Comment: @CaiusJard As a blanket statement I don't think that's correct, as you can see in the above code the object is created within (for example) GetChanges. I know that pointers are "evil" for a lot of programmers, but IMO they have their place, especially when it makes the code cleaner, more robust, easier to understand, and easier to maintain. I don't want my code to be fragile and 5x the size because of some ideological reason. I don't think this is the place for that debate anyway.

Comment: *"I don't think it's possible to update the value of a variable on a parent object without passing it byref."*. Of course it is. That's the whole point of reference types. When you assign one variable to another (passing a method argument is just that) then the contents of the variable is copied, i.e. the value. For reference types, that value is a reference. Only the reference is copied, not the object it refers to. Passing a reference type by value is already passing a reference. Passing a reference type by reference is passing a reference to a reference.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I guess I'm missing something. An integer is a reference type? Or an integer member variable is a reference type?

Comment: @jmcilhinney we must have got our wires crossed somewhere, I tried running CheckChange as you suggested and it didn't work. If you are really positive that it is unnecessary to pass byref, then something is wrong with my environment. Could you confirm that is definitely what you are talking about?

Comment: Classes are reference types and structures a value type. Declare a reference type parameter `ByRef` ONLY if you want to assign a new object to the parameter inside the method and have that reflected outside the method. Do the same for value type parameters in the same scenario but ALSO declare value type parameters `ByRef` if you want to make changes to the existing value. You are treating reference types like value types. You need to spend some time learning the difference. I'll say no more on the subject here.

Comment: I think you just asserted that declaring a thousand boolean properties on a class and using reflection to enumerate and examine them would be a superior choice to storing them in an array, for a production environment.. ?

Comment: @jmcilhinney As far as I am aware that's exactly what I did. I'm not sure if it wasn't clear how the code was supposed to work, but the "side effects" are intentional. Eg "Change = NewV" is supposed to be reflected outside the method. Is there any particular usage you have problem with? It feels like you are just making general statements and I'm not seeing how it applies.

Comment: @CaiusJard No, it's just example code. The real code has many differences that are not relevant to the question. If you are really interested, I believe by last count there's around 300 members of 3 dozen types. Putting everything in an array would lead to all kinds of horrible unreadable code. Yes, it would be ideal for this exact situation, but the class has dozens of other methods that would be practically unreadable. You would get weird stuff like all_variables[54] = all_variables[13] * all_variables[144] + all_variables[2] which is absolutely terrible for me!

Comment: I didn't see that you had edited your post. I wasn't suggesting that you get rid of every `ByRef`. I could see that there were a couple of reasonable ones there. You had pretty much every parameter declared `ByRef` though. That was my issue, but maybe I kept complaining when you'd already fixed that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ah ok... Like I said before, this was hastily cut down example code, I undoubtedly cut out parts that required references and perhaps caused confusion. Thanks for your concern though.

Comment: If you want to see how Microsoft do it, take a look at the reference source for something that tracks changes, like a DataRow

Comment: Just because properties are backed by an array doesn't mean you have to use the array in your code; use the properties

Comment: @CaiusJard That's true, but even so that's a large amount of work, these aren't simple members in the first place. I will look at DataRow as you suggest.

Comment: Ultimately they become simple members when you drill into them enough times.. Equality/Cloning etc can either be shallow or deep, and if deep they can be thus recursively - it's not a huge amount of work to create something that recurses and asks all members for their differences. Ultimately it's what you'll end up doing with a reflective solution anyway

Answer (score 0):

On the subject of the question, code in situations like this can often be simplified by using a bit of Reflection. I am yet to test this but I think that this method should work:

```vb
Private Sub UpdateIfNotEqual(source As Foo, changes As Foo, fieldName As String)
    Dim fooType = GetType(Foo)
    Dim field = fooType.GetField(fieldName)

    Dim currentValue = field.GetValue(Me)
    Dim sourceValue = field.GetValue(source)

    If Not currentValue.Equals(sourceValue) Then
        field.SetValue(Me, sourceValue)
        field.SetValue(changes, sourceValue)
    End If
End Sub
```

You'd call it like so:

```vb
UpdateIfNotEqual(F, Changes, NameOf(B1))
UpdateIfNotEqual(F, Changes, NameOf(B2))
'...
UpdateIfNotEqual(F, Changes, NameOf(B1000))
```

If the fields really were numbered then you could even use a loop:

```vb
For i = 1 To 1000
    UpdateIfNotEqual(F, Changes, $"B{i}")
Next
```

The drawback is that Reflection is very slow. It may not be a big deal for this much data but only testing would tell you for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. Considering Foo is known, would it increase speed to keep field as static variables? Or is .GetValue the slow part? As for the field numbering, no they are not numbered like that, it's just example code.

Comment: Storing the `FieldInfo` objects may help but I think that `GetValue` and `SetValue` will be the biggest bottleneck. I'd suggest testing and profiling to see if the difference is significant.

Comment: It seems the solution is a bit more complex, because if a nullable is nothing then calling field.GetValue(Me) fails with a null reference exception. Since we can't read the value to figure out of it's nothing, Id have to catch the exception. Suddenly a <10 line clean method is 20 -30 lines of exception handlers... Maybe not the best idea!

Comment: You wouldn't need an exception handling. You'd just need to use a bit more Reflection to determine whether the field type is nullable and treat it accordingly.

Comment: I'm not experienced with vb.net reflection so I'm not really sure what that would look like. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user-63873687 You might run into some trouble with some of the underlying .NET behavior for nullables if you're doing anything with converting between enums and ints.  If this is a scenario you'll have to deal with, I can expand on what you need to do to make it work.

Comment: Determining whether a type is nullable: `theType.IsGenericType AndAlso theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(GetType(Nullable(Of )))`

Answer (score 0):

**Reflection**

```
Class Foo
    Public B1 As Boolean
    Public B2 As Boolean
    Public B3 As Boolean

    Public C1 As Integer = Rnd() * 100

    Function GetChanges(F As Foo) As Foo
        Dim Changes As New Foo()
        For Each field As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In F.GetType.GetFields.Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("B"))
            If field.GetValue(F) <> Me.GetType.GetField(field.Name).GetValue(F) Then
                Changes.GetType.GetField(field.Name).SetValue(Changes, field.GetValue(F))
            Else
                '????????
            End If
        Next
        Return Changes
    End Function
End Class
```

**PropertyDescriptor**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Class Foo
    Property B1 As Integer
    Property B2 As Boolean
    Property Text As String
    Function GetChanges(F As Foo) As Foo
        Dim Changes As New Foo()
        Dim pdc As PropertyDescriptorCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(F)
        For Each pd As PropertyDescriptor In pdc
            If pd.IsReadOnly = False Then
                If pd.IsBrowsable = True Then
                    'add more conditions if needed
                    Changes.GetType.GetProperty(pd.Name).SetValue(Changes, pd.GetValue(F), Nothing)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return Changes
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The question specifically states that it's about fields rather that properties. You could use `Type.GetFields` to get the field names in a loop, assuming that this needs to be done for all fields or it's practical to exclude those that don't need it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,Thank you for clarification ,but my question is what about if **F.B1 = True** and current instance **B1=True** , **Changes.B1** still has its initialized value = **false**